# An issue with the security headers in a Node JS application

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, response-headers, helmet.js

I am facing an issue regarding setting of security headers in a Node JS application.
In the project I am working upon there is a need of setting some response headers like **content-security-policy, noSniff, xss-filter and hsts** headers. I am setting these headers with the help of helmet package. The problem I am facing is that when theses headers are not setting up all the time on all the pages instead these are only setting up on very first time when we are going to a page and the second time we come back to the same page then these headers will not be seen on that page.

One thing I noticed in this that only the static pages have this behaviour but the pages that are being served up through backend data excludes this behaviour.

I surfed a lot on google but found nothing related to it. Please respond on this as soon as possible.

Express version: 4.17.1
Helmet Version: 4.6.0

Comment: Can you add some code to your question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Helmet maintainer here. Some code would be useful. It might also be that the order of your middlewares is wrong, but it's hard to tell without code.